# How to retrieve a php batch parameter's value?

Tags: php, command-line-arguments

I understand that PHP's `$argv` returns an array with parameters provided at the command line.

I was wondering if there is a function to retrieve the value assigned to a parameter or not. For example:

```
php mybatch.php --xxx=3
```

Such function `f($argv,"xxx")` would return 3. Or do I have to implement it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [getopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php) offers a bit more details and features when dealing with command-line parameters:
You want to pass a long parameter, so this will do:

```
<?php
$opts = getopt(null, ['xxx:']);

if (isset($opts['xxx'])) {
    echo 'Parameter xxx: ' . $opts['xxx'];
}
```

Result:

```
Parameter xxx: 3
```